# Links not working in my error page

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, hyperlink

I have just created a personalised error 404 page and redirected to it through htaccess file.

When an error is tiped from the main folder, links work perfectly.

```
Ex: www.domain.com/tipingerror.hmlt
```

But when an error is tiped from the subfolders, links do not work.

```
Ex: www.domain.com/folder/tipingerror.lhtm
```

Links in the 404 page are like:

```
<li>
    <a href="../ordenador/castellano/contacto.html">Contact</a>
</li>
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Without posting some code one can only guess! My guess is that you use relative paths in your HTML.

Comment: One link is for example: <li><a href="../ordenador/castellano/contacto.html">Contact</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative paths don't work if the URL has a different folder depth. Change them to absolute paths like

```
<li>
    <a href="/ordenador/castellano/contacto.html">Contact</a>
</li>
```

[Here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) is a cool article about relative / absolute paths. It might help you if you have more issues.

Comment: That worked, thank you for your time and for the article. With no doubt I will take a look at it.